# Android: How to go from MainActivity to Surfaceview

Tags: java, android, android-activity, surfaceview

I have an Activity GamePanel which extends Surfaceview with the context code below.

```
public GamePanel(Context context)
{
super(context);
this.mContext = context;
mContext = getContext();

//add the callback to the surfaceholder to intercept events
getHolder().addCallback(this);

thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);

//make gamePanel focusable so it can handle events
setFocusable(true);
}
```

Now I used this to go to my MainMenu class from GamePanel.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainMenu.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Here is my question: How do I go back from the MainMenu Activity to the Gamepanel Activity that extends Surfaceview when I press a button?

EDIT: Here is the top line of my GamePanel Activity:

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
```

Comment: `Activity` cannot extend `SurfaceView`. You do something wrong. Show the top lines of the class, where you see `public class GamePanel extends...`, so we see what is your GamePanel really

Comment: Here is the top line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, it is not an `Activity`. Please stop calling it an `Activity`. It is a `SurfaceView`, which is a subclass of `View`, and is **not** a subclass of `Activity`.
To start activity, you just need a `Context` instance.
Every `View` can provide an instance of `Context` by calling `getContext()`
So to start another `Activity` from a `View`, you can call

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainMenu.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
getContext().startActivity(intent );
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my terminology. But im in the activity MainMenu and from there I want to go to the SurfaceView. How to I reference the SurfaceView context in the MainMenu activity?

Comment: @DavidPrabhu, oh, sorry, messed up your question. Ok. Your `SurfaceView` is owned by some Activity. You should start that activity same way as you've started `MainMenu`

Comment: @DavidPrabhu, sample code depends on your code. Nodody knows where you use your `SurfaceView` (`GamePanel`). First you show it.